# Changing pages spring boot application

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I having problem changing pages. So what I have is a button and when that user press that button a ajax Post is called. Here the example:

```
 $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(project),
        url: "/saveProject",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('done');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('error while post');
        }
    });

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String saveProject(@RequestBody Project newProject, Authentication authentication) {
    projectService.saveProjectNew(newProject, authentication);

    return "mywork.html";

}
```

So in the end I want to be redirect to mywork.html from the page I'm currently on. However nothing happens and I stay on same page. I'm probably missing something that I don't know. Quiet new to this.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Spring; you're mixing AJAX and traditional HTML form post. Learn about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the page into the mywork.html
You need to write the code once you get the response from the Ajax call
So under the success function of Ajax you should use

```
windows.location.href = "Your context path"+"/mywork.html";
```

Please refer the reference code below:

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(project),
    url: "/saveProject",
    success: function (data) {
        windows.location.href = "Your context path"+"/mywork.html";

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error while post');
    }
});
```

Here the spring web client code will not divert the call to the mywork.html.

All the call will be diverted only through the Ajax call.

```
return "mywork.html";
```

This code is only used to model your response which been retrieved after calling the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Http redirection could be triggered from both the back-end as well as the front-end ajax code that you have posted.

For the redirection to work from the ui , you can add the window redirection like @Anurag pointed out in his answer on the ajax success callback.

But in your example you are trying to redirect the user to a new page from the backend endpoint itself. So provided that you already have a controller returning the view for the mapping `/mywork.html` in order for the redirect to work from the spring backend side , you need to do the following :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProject(@RequestBody Project newProject, Authentication authentication) {
    projectService.saveProjectNew(newProject, authentication);
    return "redirect:/mywork.html";

}
```

or using `ResponseEntity` like :

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setLocation(URI.create(newUrl));
return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
```

In your code you were using the annotation `@ResponseBody` for the controller method which basically makes the endpoint a rest endpoint returning json by default. So , for redirection to work remove the annotation and make it a normal controller method returning view.

Still if you want to redirect from a rest endpoint then use `HttpServletResponse` like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveProject(@RequestBody Project newProject, Authentication authentication, HttpServletResponse response) {
    projectService.saveProjectNew(newProject, authentication);
    response.sendRedirect("url-here");   
}
```

For more information [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward).